# Finding a formula for a series INDUCTION

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> **11.** Find a formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i(i+1)}$ and prove that it holds for all $n \geq 1$.

How does this relate from proofing this by induction and making a formula. Confused how you would find the formula. How can I approach this, or maybe give me an answer and show me how you did this in detail? Would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Think about how you would use the fact that

$$\frac1{i (i+1)} = \frac1{i}-\frac1{i+1}$$

Write out individual terms in the sum using this formula and see what happens.

Comment: not exactly sure how this relates? how did you get that its 1/i(i+1) = 1/i - 1/i+1

Comment: @RoyKesserwani: Do you understand the summation notation?

Comment: Yes I am, its a summation of a series

Comment: @RoyKesserwani: OK then, substitute each term in the series with the formula on the right of the equal sign.  It should look like $$1-\frac12 + \frac12-\frac13+\cdots$$